# Tomcat 9 Rewrite with ORDS and Oracle Apex

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

How to set URL Rewrite (like mod_Rewrite in Apache) with Tomcat (8.x, 9.x - which supports rewrite natively ) and ORDS and Oracle Apex  (with no Apache in front)?

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Yes. according to instructions below.

Comment: Great. Just tweeted it out for other ORDS users.

Answer (score 1):

**Background :** 
Assumed already installed :

- Oracle application express ( Apex 5.x in my case).
- Tomcat 9 (applicable for tomcat 8 as well).
- Ords (3.x in my case)
- Configuration described with with no Apache in front of Tomcat.

**Installation (written out of my head) :**

1. Go to : /usr/share/tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4/webapps/ords/WEB-INF (according to your pathes)

   - [Download rewrite.config and place it inside the WEB-INF directory](https://www.dropbox.com/s/if8sn3dvjdn04av/rewrite.config?dl=1)
2. Go to : /usr/share/tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4/webapps/ords/META-INF (according to your pathes)

   - [Download context.xml and place it inside META-INF directory](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia13sa1xkdhblf1/context.xml?dl=1)
3. stop and start your tomcat

   - /usr/share/tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4/sbin/shutdown.sh
   - /usr/share/tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4/bin/startup.sh
4. Test it : http://yourdomain:port/ords , should lead you to : http://www.companyname3.com/

Comment: Not sure if (I assume) your dropbox links are suitable for SO

Comment: Thanks. what exactly do you mean ? This is my paid dropbox account (not temp)